# NativeScript : Filter Folders

Tags: nativescript

I want to get the list of contents of a Folder ( located in SD-Card ) and put it in an array, and separate Folders from Files.

right now I am using this:

```sh
const fs = require("tns-core-modules/file-system");
const root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
dir = fs.path.join( root , '/Parole' );
let documents = fs.Folder.fromPath( dir );

documents.getEntities()
.then((entities) => {
    entities.forEach((entity) => {
        console.log(entity);
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.stack);
});
```

but `entity` contanis no info but `name & path` for Folders ( and for Files which has no EXT ) , How can I recognize if it refers to a folder or not?

(p.s. I am Not using any Framework in my project)

**(p.s. I have some Files with-out Any EXT in my project!!!!)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Folder` apis to distinguish between folder and file.

```
entities.forEach((entity) => {
    if (fs.Folder.exists(entity.path)) {
       // Folder
    } else {
       // File
    }
});
```